# replacing a tcl variable that is already loaded on widget window

Tags: variables, widget, tcl

I need some help to replace one variable that is already loaded on a toplevel/window widget.
I have a toplevel (.), with the title:

```
set USER "Adam" 

wm title . "Main Menu - WELCOME $USER!"
```

and the variable `USER` is loaded when starting the program.

if i use:

```
set USER John
```

How can i replace the `$USER` value, or update the entire widget, to show `John` instead `Adam`.

Thank YOU!!

I tried the command `trace` but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `trace` command is exactly how you detect that a variable (usually at the global or namespace level; tracing local variables is supported but not usually a good idea and very expensive computationally) has changed. It's just that you need to set it up right. By *far* the easiest way is to **use a procedure** for the callback:

```
proc USERchanged {args} { # We can ignore the arguments; we know what's happened
    global USER
    wm title . "Main Menu - WELCOME $USER"
}

trace add variable USER write USERchanged
```

You can also use a lambda term or method call, but the syntax is a bit more complex. Here's a lambda:

```
trace add variable USER write [list apply {args {
    global USER
    wm title . "Main Menu - WELCOME $USER"
}}]
```

Note the use of `list` to build the actual callback.

---

*Technically* you can put a script directly in the callback, but **this is not recommended** as it is easy to get wrong and awkward/annoying to debug. Use a procedure instead.

```
trace add variable USER write {wm title . "Main Menu - WELCOME $::USER"; #}
```

Comment: Hi Donal!! thank you for your help! i'm your fan, because with your answers in this forum, I managed to evolve a lot in the concepts of tcl programming...(English is not my native language, so it's an extra difficulty). thank you for you reply to my question...I am very grateful for your wisdom.